# How to display a Modal popup in a Blazor Server Application

Tags: c#, electron, parent-child, blazor-server-side, electron.net

I am creating a Blazor Desktop Application. For this I am using Blazor Server Application with ElectronNET.API. I have been trying to launch a modal popup upon clicking a button or a menu item.
I tried using `CreateWindowAsync(BrowserWindowOptions options, string loadUrl = "http://localhost");` method. Using this I am able to launch a window but it is not modal eventhough I have specified `modal=true` in the BrowserWindow options.

```
var windowOptions = new BrowserWindowOptions
                    {
                        AutoHideMenuBar = true,
                        AlwaysOnTop = true,
                        Type = "popup",
                        Width = 500,
                        Height = 300,
                        Center = true,
                        Modal = true,                       
                        Show = true
                    };
```

The `Modal` option has the comment that it will work only when the window is a child window but I don't know how to create a BrowserWindow as a child window without the Parent option. I specified the parent window with the `BrowserWindow.SetParentWindow` method after creating the BrowserWindow, but it didn't work modally.

It would be helpful if you could suggest a way to achieve modal popup in Blazor Desktop Application